# Sqlmap Sleepy User-Agent

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

I was testing Burp Suite Crawl on some old php sites I made and it found Sleepy User-Agent
SQL injection vulnerability

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100
> Safari/537.36 **'+(select*from(select(sleep(20)))a)+'**

And I am wondering how this can be applicable in `sqlmap`, I found that `sqlmap` can be used in Boolean-based and Time-dependent SQL injection (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708851/combination-of-boolean-based-and-time-dependent-sql-injection-in-sqlmap) but I can not figure it out how to use it in this User-Agent vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

`sqlmap` have in test patterns Boolean-based with Time-dependent SQL injection but you must specify where you want to test SQL injections patterns.

So in my case I used option `--user-agent="*"` which should be empty user agent and `*` is specifying where this patterns will be tested (because in my case it do not require have something in it).

One more tip - when someone is using `sqlmap` over `tor` and want to test Time-dependent SQL injection, you must specify `--time-sec=` to atleast `4-5` seconds due the `tor` network speed.